# Bus error: 10 in bison and flex on mac os

Tags: c, macos, bison, flex-lexer

Here is the code in question:

#### calc.y

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    void yyerror(char *);
    int yylex(void);

    int sym[26];
%}
%token INTEGER VARIABLE
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%% 

program:
        program statement '\n'
        | /* NULL */
        ;

statement:
        expression                  { printf("%d\n", $1); }
        | VARIABLE '=' expression   { sym[$1] = $3; }
        ;

expression:
        INTEGER
        | VARIABLE                      { $$ = sym[$1]; }
        | expression '+' expression     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        | expression '-' expression     { $$ = $1 - $3; }
        | expression '*' expression     { $$ = $1 * $3; }
        | expression '/' expression     { $$ = $1 / $3; }
        | '(' expression ')'            { $$ = $2; }
        ;

%%

void yyerror(char *s){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void){
    yyparse();
}
```

---

#### calc.l

```
%{
    #include "calc.tab.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    void yyerror(char *);
%}

%% 
[a-z]       {
                yylval = *yytext - 'a';
                return VARIABLE;
}

[0-9]+      {
                yylval = atoi(yytext);
                return INTEGER;
}

[-+()=/*\n]     { return *yytext; }

[\t]    ;

.           yyerror("Unkown Character");

%%

int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
}
```

When I run above code with the following commands, it works well.

```
$ bison -d calc.y
$ flex calc.l
```

However, when it is run like this:

```
$ gcc lex.yy.c calc.tab.c -o app
```

this command does not work well. And I am getting following `error`:

```
Bus error: 10
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening ?

Or, how can I solve this error ?

Please need help.

Comment: I can't reproduce that same behavior on my arch. No bug, it's work has expected. Maybe you should include your bison, flex and gcc version.

Comment: @Stargateur . How ca I  generate `app`.? I have tried both `gcc lex.yy.c calc.tab.c -o app` and `valgrind gcc lex.yy.c calc.tab.c -o app`.  But it would not work .

Comment: What is your gcc version ? `gcc -v`

Comment: @Stargateur . `$ gcc -v 
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Bus error: 10`

Comment: well... upgrade your gcc with your package manager... I can't imagine you are still at gcc-4.2.1. Maybe this will fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make up your mind as to whether VARIABLE is `sym[$1]` or just the index into `sym[]`.myouve used it both ways in your grammar. Judging by your lexer it is the index. In fact I don't see any necessity for `sym[]` at all.

And you didn't get the bus error when you generate the .c files *or* when you compiled them. You got it when you *executed* your application.